# Can you charge while using non-standard movement like flying?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement, flight, charge

Flying is a common ability in Pathfinder; so is using special attack options like [charging](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Charge). What's not clear is when they're used together.

Are you able to charge while flying? Can you do so while burrowing, swimming, climbing (provided you have the correct movement for it), or other special movement types which have a specific speed that don't require extra movement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Charge:
http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html#charge

(Edit: Assuming the other requirements are met as the other answer points out, such as any difficult terrain (high winds for example))

"Up to your speed or less"

So long as you have a flight speed, you can charge while flying - similarly for regular moving, climbing, swimming and burrowing. See feats like Death from above for corroboration.
http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/death-from-above-combat

You can't however charge while making those movement types without the relevant speed.

This is easier to see with climbing or swimming as flying without a flight speed generally gets referred to as 'falling'. But, for example, dropping* downwards from a tree in an ambush wouldn't count as a charge due to lacking the relevant movement speed, though you would probably get +1 for being on higher ground.

(While the climb skill specifically mentions not being able to run while climbing, even with a climb speed, RAW the ability to run or not doesn't actually hinder your ability to charge; RAW the two are different things. Similarly the swim skill limits running to a straight line, even with a swim speed.)

*You could however jump downwards (e.g. [Branch Pounce](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/branch-pounce-combat/)), using the acrobatics skill, though this jumping charge would still need to be in a straight and unobstructed line. With a successful jump check, I would count this as movement made using your regular overland speed.

Comment: I had not read that feat and it does help, thank you.

Comment: What about Branch Pounce, which says "When charging a target from jumping down from above"? https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/branch-pounce-combat/

Comment: Very good point. I wasn't aware of the debate on jumping while charging until now (e.g. https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2s73x?Charging-and-jumping). My initial reaction to this, is that as a GM I think I would allow it so long as it is a jump (as per acrobatics rules), not falling, and the movement doesn't prevent you from following the requirement of moving in a straight line for the charge — and I'd then count that charge as using using regular land speed, not flying.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can charge while using alternate movement modes as long as the other requirements for a charge are met.

Answer (score 0):

Not all moving forms allow charging. [Burrowing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/movement#TOC-Burrow) Creatures are specifically not allowed to run or charge.

Flying creatures are allowed to charge, "run" in a straight line, and make charge-like dive attacks with claws or talons.

Comment: Hello and welcome! You can take the [tour] to learn more about the site. I think this answer could be improved by including the quote you are referencing. Thank you for contributing and happy gaming!

Comment: Isn’t MM1 a D&D 3.5 book, not a Pathfinder book? Even if they say the same thing, you should probably cite the PF rule instead.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It may be that the user *can't* quote the *Pathfinder* version of the movement mode burrow. So far as I'm aware—while dozens of *Pathfinder* creatures possess burrow speeds—the game itself hasn't actually published its own burrowing rules. (See [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Burrow_Ex).)