# How does underwater combat work with Soul Knives?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, underwater

How does [underwater combat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/wilderness/terrain/aquatic-terrain/) work with [Soul Knives](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/#TOC-Blade-Skills)'/[Bolts'](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/soulbolt)?

Do they get the same penalties as regular weapons under water? Does a Soulbolt's Mind Bolt still have -2 per 5 feet ranged weapon penalties under water with Launch the Soulbolt ability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal rules for water combat would apply, however you can have the weapon deal piercing damage which will allow you to do normal damage if you have a swim speed, firm footing or freedom of movement as per the water combat rules.

> When shaping her weapon and assigning abilities to it, the soulknife chooses whether it will deal bludgeoning, piercing, or slashing damage.

Mind Bolts from the [soulbolt](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/soulbolt/) archetype should follow the range weapon water combat rules.

Comment: Since you mentioned "swim speed" then that means you can charge under water or on the surface of the water to right?

Comment: Yes you can charge with any type of movement e.g. fly or swim as long as you are not hindered in your movement. So if you have a swim speed or freedom of movement, it does not hinder your movement and you can charge. See http://legacy.aonprd.com/coreRuleBook/combat.html#charge and https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64365/can-you-charge-while-using-non-standard-movement-like-flying.